# (adb) How to Backup things from /data/data using a shell terminal emulator on the same device without root?

Tags: adb, backup, emulators

~ I have Nexus 5 running Android L 5.1.1

~ I want to backup one App cach from /data/data

~ I don't concider rooting my device

~ I installed a Shell Terminal Emulator from the app store.

~ I've already tried some commands like:

> adb backup -noapk com.google.android.app

But it didn't work (gives a 0kb file)

And sometimes gives error: (adb: unable to connect for backup) {I'm already a developer and debugging is on}.

Then I tried this one:

> time adb shell ls -l -a | grep '^[^l]' | sed -e 's/^d.* ([^ ]*)\r$/mkdir -p sav/\1; adb pull /\1 sav/\1/' -e 's/-.* ([^ ]*)\r$/adb pull /\1 sav/\1/' | /bin/bash
>   It gives some not found errors !

Is that possible? 'Cause I heard that a lot of people succeed to backup things without root, but using adb with android sdk on a PC.

Comment: Look at this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/95577

Comment: By *"one App cach"* do you mean a particular app's cache?

Comment: @Firelord Yes, for example, the app X downloads some content to /data/data folder, and I want to reach those files without rooting my devixe :)